# how dealing with some time series in LSTM model?

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am a new keras user and I would like to easily understand how to build an lstm model.

In my data, I have lot of users, which have many sequences, as below :

```
user 1 :
         X            Labels
    sequence 1   [ 0, 1 , 0, 1]
    sequence 2   [ 0, 1 , 0, 1]
    sequence 3   [ 0, 1 , 0, 1
    sequence 4          ?

user 2 :
        X             labels
    sequence 1   [ 0, 1 , 0, 1]
    sequence 2   [ 0, 1 , 0, 1]
    sequence 3          ?
```

Each user has sequences series, but necessarily the same lenght series. And each series correspond to a multi label series.
My goal is to predict the label for the next sequence of each user, with considering the last sequences (as time series).

I succed that, when I use only one user. Indeed, I make an lstm input like
(Batch size, time step, Features) where batch size equal to one because I have one user, and time step is equal to the number of sequences and features is equal to the sequences lenght.

```
model_rnn = Sequential()
model_rnn.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 20)))
model_rnn.add(TimeDistributedDense(nb_classes)) 
model_rnn.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01,decay=1e-6)
model_rnn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
X_train = X_train.reshape((1,50,20))
y_train = y_train.reshape((1,50,109))
model_rnn.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=200)
```

I have two questions:
Is it important, when I fit the model, that the shuffle=False ?
and Should I put the stateful option equal to True when I define the LSTM?

Already, I got a good performance for one user. I would like to use the same approach on all the users. But I don't see how I can build the input for all the users.

For example, I want to learn the old user sequences and predict his next sequence,
Will I be forced to train an LSTM for each user? Or I can lean the time sequence serie of each user in ONE LSTM ?
Especially if I use one LSTM and I would like to predict the next sequence of one user, how the model could predict the good sentence like it doesn't know this own old sequence on the training data.

Note, it is important to consider that the sequences users are independent between them.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it important, when I fit the model, that the shuffle=False ?**

No, it is not important unless you set the stateful to True. See your next question's answer below.

---

**Should I put the stateful option equal to True when I define the LSTM?**

A LSTM has cells and is therefore stateful by definition (not the same stateful meaning as used in Keras). Fabien Chollet gives this definition of statefulness:

> stateful: Boolean (default False). If True, the last state for each
>   sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the
>   sample of index i in the following batch.

So, if you set the LSTM as stateless in Keras, the cell states are reset at each sequence. With the stateful mode set, all the states are propagated to the next batch. It means that the state of the sample located at index i, X_{i} will be used in the computation of the sample X_{i+bs} in the next batch, where *bs* is the batch size (no shuffling).

Please note, by default, Keras shuffles (permutes) the samples X and the dependencies between X_{i} and X_{i+1} are lost. So, if you set the **stateful option to True**, make sure you set the `shuffle=False`.

---

**I want to learn the old user sequences and predict his next sequence, Will I be forced to train an LSTM for each user? Or I can lean the time sequence serie of each user in ONE LSTM?**

I believe, you need one LSTM since it worked well for one user. You can consider all the sequences for all users as your training data as you are doing for one user.